# UITableView frame going out of view

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I have a application that I'm developing in swift. I added a UITableView in a ViewController. The UITableView frame is going out of view in width. I have already checked that the width of TableView in Interface Builder is within the view.

Comment: if you're using autolayout make sure that you'd assigned **Leading** and **Trailing** constraints.

Comment: i am not using autolayout.

Comment: so you have to layout subviews (and TableView one of them) by your own. When you creates view controller xib its view default size is 600x600px. And when you run your app on iPhone view will shrink or stretch both horizontally and vertically, according to screen size,  but your tableView will not. I'll highly recommend you to use autolayout, but if you can't - override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and change tableView's frame there

Comment: how do i use auto layout? i am new to swift and iOS. please help

Comment: check this guide first
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html